# Can I install the latest version of OpenSSL and Apache on Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP4?

Tags: apache-2.4, openssl, sles

I couldn't find minimum OS requirements for OpenSSL and Apache. 
I would like to know if it is possible to have OpenSSL 1.0.2 and Apache 2.4.x on Linux SUSE Enterprise Server SP4.

Comment: Your suse version comes with apache 2.2 for what i can see. You definitely can use Apache 2.4 and openssl 1.0.2, you have this options:

Answer (score 1):

Your suse version comes with apache 2.2 for what i can see. You definitely can use Apache 2.4 and openssl 1.0.2, you have this options:

- Build openssl and apache from sources - Easy to do, but you'll have to rebuild every time there's some security problem ecc.
- Find some precompiled versions compatible with your requirements - in this case some other person is compiling and packaging Apache and openssl for you, this may have security implications / you will be trusting this some other person . organization. Here's a link in case: https://forums.suse.com/showthread.php?4138-Upgrade-to-Apache-2-4-x

In either case, you better ask to your support contact in SuSE as you're using the Enterprise version

Comment: We don't have a support contact. I think our support ran out a while ago

Comment: Well, in this case as you don't have support anyway you can use the Leap version which includes apache 2.4. Or if you can't replace the operating system you can compile openssl and apache